# How to get Majority approval without canceling outstanding request change tasks

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

In SPD 2010 I have created a workflow that requires majority approval of a group before pushing the document to a separate read only library and cancelling the tasks assigned to the other group members. My issue is that it is possible for some members to request a change while others approve the document. I do not want the document to be approved if their are changes that still need to be addressed. Any suggestions.

Thanks, 
Melissa

Comment: Melissa, Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Thanks, James